# Create decorator with parameters and access the decorated function parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-decorator

I want to write a log decorator that logs every time the function (in which the decorator decorates) is called. I want to log a key that the decorator accepts as a parameter and the arguments that the function was sent with.

So far I know how to write a simple log function that logs the function arguments but cant accept any parameters:

```
export function logger(
  target: Object,
  key: string,
  descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
) {
  const original = descriptor.value;
  descriptor.value = function() {
    const targetName = target.constructor.name;
    const args = JSON.stringify(arguments);
    console.log(`Calling ${targetName}.${key} with ${JSON.stringify(arguments)}`);
    const result = original.apply(this, arguments);
    return result;
  };
  return descriptor;
}
```

I also know how to write a decorator that accepts  parameters:

```
log(logData: { value: string; target?: string }) {
    return function(
      target: Object,
      key: string,
      descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
    ) {
      console.log(`Key: ${logData.value}, Target: ${logData.target}`);

    };
  }
```

So you probably can guess that I am missing a link here which is to write a log decorator that can accepts a key as a parameter and logs this key with the arguments that the decorated function was called with.

I have a working example of those 2 decorators here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udi-decorators?file=src%2Fapp%2Flogger.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured it out.
My solution works. I wanted to build a decorator for function that will save data each time the function is called. It will save a unique key for each function (it will be given with the decorator) and will send also the parameters that were sent to this function.

```
logWithData(logData: { value: string; target?: string }) {
    return function logger(
      target: Object,
      key: string,
      descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
    ) {
      const original = descriptor.value;
      descriptor.value = function() {
        const targetName = target.constructor.name;
        const args = JSON.stringify(arguments);
        console.log(`Key: ${logData.value}, Target: ${logData.target}, paramater: ${arguments[0]}`);
        const result = original.apply(this, arguments);
        return result;
      };
      return descriptor;
    };
  }
```

I also put this code on stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udi-decorators?file=src%2Fapp%2Flogger.ts)

Comment: That `arguments` is what I needed. Thanks.